# Rating in Google Search

Tags: google-search, rich-snippets

How to let the review rating appear in Google Search as follows?

[image: Google seach result showing a star rating]

Answer (score 1):

Implement [schema reviews](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/reviews) in your site and Google will pick up, if your site is good enough.

Make sure your rating (stars) is also visible to users, and you implement that schema to only applicable webpages, I mean don't implement in how to article or something like that.